# Xaml/Win RT - Wait for controls to be fully rendered

Tags: vb.net, async-await, winrt-async

In a winRT application, a tap on a button will render multiple controls on the page. A tap on another button will save the content of these controls.

To save the content of the controls, my code iterates the page's control collection.

The problem I have is that it happens that the user taps the save button whereas all controls are not finished rendering yet.

My question is simple: how do I manage to wait for the rendering to be complete before enabling the save button ?

```
Private Async Sub LoadControls() 
'create controls ...
'add controls to a hub section ...
'add section to a hub, myHub is defined in Xaml
myHub.Sections.Add(myHubSection)
End Sub

Private Async Sub ReadControls()
For Each hubSection in MyHub
'...
'not all controls are available here, because they are not yet rendered
Next
End Sub

Private Async Sub LoadButton(sender as object, e as RoutedEventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
Await LoadControls()
End Sub

Private Async Sub SaveButton(sender as object, e as RoutedEventArgs) Handles LoadButton.Click
Await ReadControls()
End Sub
```

I have tried a lot of solutions using Dispatcher and stuff, but none worked.
Is there a simple solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Does that code compile without warnings or errors?

Comment: @PauloMorgado The code above is for illustration purposes of the entire process, real code has no interest (to my opinion). Imagine I add 40 controls at run time to the hub, which takes say 5 seconds to render. If I run the 'readcontrols' function before those 5 seconds (this can happen because the rendering is asynchronous), I don't get 40 controls, but only a subset. I need some sort of event saying 'rendering is complete'. What do you think ?

Comment: You should post a working compilable example.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, I think, would be to wait for the Dispatcher thread to be idle. If there is images in the control to render, you would have to parse the VisualTree, find each image and wait for them to be rendered (using the ImageOpened event) :

Sorry for my C# :)

```
    // Do "nothing" when the dispacher is idle
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Idle, () => { });
```